# Date field validation

Tags: validation-rule, configuration

I have a custom field "Requested Delivery Date" and the requirement is

1. When user enters date it should be more than 10 days from Today
2. This rule will only apply to 2 record types which are Demonstration and Evaluation.

Comment: please take some time to review [ask] and update your question

Comment: So what's the problem? What have you tried so far? Paste your validation rule and then, I can help you modify it to meet the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sudo code for your validation rule:

```
AND(
     Requested_Delivery_Date__c <  TODAY() + 10 ,
     OR(
          RecordTypeID = 'ID OF Demonstration',   
          RecordTypeID = 'ID OF Demonstration',   
     }   
   )
```

If this formula /rule return true then show error message that Requested Delivery Date must be latter than today + 10 when record type is Demonstration OR Evaluation.